# How to create a navigationController inside a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have only ever used the navigatoinController from the apple start up code from xcode.

I am wondering if and how I could create a navigation controller inside another navigation controller.. but just hide the menu of the "subnavigationcontroller"..

I have been messing around with UI stuff and have tried to create an array of views that animate on the top view of the stack but its causing too many head achs.. thus I have decided to go for something that can handle all the memory stuff for me... its just im not really sure how to allocate the navigation controller in a view.. normally its done in the app delegate etc..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like related http://www.kickasslabs.com/2009/07/03/uinavigationcontroller-tricks/

Comment: his one is quite complex and doing a bunch of stuff I don't need too, but I should be able to fish out what I am trying to do with his code... ill post a response with how I go once I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, you can make use of container views. Add a container view in the view controller you need to add navigation controller then connect its embed segue to your child nav controller. It will looks like following.
[image]

And after running it will looks like 
[image]